# Dynamic Change of URL-Referenced Picture

Tags: php, css, wordpress, elementor

I am utilizing Elementor to design a webpage on Wordpress and currently have an image in the body of this page.

This image utilizes the "Insert from URL" option as opposed to pulling from the media library. I would like functionality on the page where a user can click buttons to switch which image is displayed by passing a php string into the URL, which would ideally change the URL of the picture.

The goal is to reduce strain on the web server itself. The picture URL structure is consistent, and is as follows:

```
www.example.com/graphics/someregion_somevariable.png
```

It is possible to leverage CSS code (inside the Elementor picture widget) to directly change the URL referenced picture off a php string passed into the website URL?  What CSS and PHP code would need to be leveraged to execute this? Thank you!

Comment: Make sure that if you do this, you validate the user input in some way. You wouldn’t want them to put in a random script file and get it to execute! ;)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript Solution

Using URL params to indicate which picture to display:

- `https://example.com/page?picture=picture_1`
- `https://example.com/page?picture=picture_2`
- `https://example.com/page?picture=picture_3`

You can conditionally load a specific image based on this URL Parameter:

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const pictureParam = urlParams.get('picture')

const pictureUrl = switch (pictureParam) {
  case 'picture_1':
    return 'www.example.com/graphics/picture_1.png'
    break

  case 'picture_2':
    return 'www.example.com/graphics/another-picture.png'
    break

  case 'picture_3':
    return 'www.example.com/graphics/picture_x.png'
    break

  default:
    return 'www.example.com/graphics/fallback.png'
    break
}
```

Now you can select your image element on page and change the src to the required picture.

```js
document.querySelector('#the-image-element').src = pictureUrl
```